# Get accurate number of precisions after decimal c#

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal

I want to get accurate number of decimal places, just like if we divide 1/397, it shoulb return decimal places upto 99 digits after decimal point. I have tried in c# but its not returning me upto this accuracy level, it rounds off to 10 or 12.

Comment: just curiosity: what kind of application you're writing ?? cause 99 digits after point is plenty accurate precision...

Comment: I have read about this in a contest problem on internet, was unable to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard types available in C# offer much less precision than you're asking for:

- float - [7 digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)
- double - [15-16 digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)
- decimal - [28-29 digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

If you want better precision than these types offer then you'll have to look at using a third-party library. A list of arbitrary-precision libraries (including several for C#) can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BigFloat` from here: http://www.fractal-landscapes.co.uk/bigint.html
It is accurate up to 250 digits after decimal point.

Comment: +1 for nice library link. Yes this is what I want to achieve, but I want wondering to do this using normal c# classes or options.